# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-map

I am building a Charts Gallery using the [Recharts](https://github.com/recharts/recharts) library.

These are the files i am working on

The data fixtures is *charts.js*

```
const charts = [
  {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
  {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
  {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
  {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
  {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
  {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
  {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
];

export default charts;
```

The data is correctly imported in my store with the rest of the other datas

Then i have my *ChartsGrid.js* where the error comes from

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from './Chart';

export default class ChartsGrid extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid">
        {this.props.charts.map((chart, i) => <Chart {...this.props} key={i} i={i} chart={chart} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

and here my chart component importing modules from the recharts library

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { ResponsiveContainer, LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, ReferenceLine,
  ReferenceDot, Tooltip, CartesianGrid, Legend, Brush } from 'recharts';

export default class Chart extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { chart, i} = this.props;
    return (
        <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={charts}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
};
```

Why is it throwing this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ? What is actually undefined?

Comment: `this.props.charts.map` -> this throws the error, therefore `this.props.charts` is `undefined`

Comment: how can i define it then? the "charts" are actually defined in my store

Comment: I don't see where you imported ChartsGrid.. I would expect you to <ChartsGrid charts={charts}/>

Comment: Also, ChartsGrid is your parent component, does it have a parent? the parent should pass the "charts" to it as property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not imported the *charts.js* file before using the `charts` array.

You could import the *charts.js* file where you use the `ChartsGrid` component and pass `charts` as a prop:

```
import charts from './charts'
...
<ChartsGrid charts={charts} />
```

Or, you could use the `charts` object directly in *ChartsGrid.js* instead of `this.props`.

```
import charts from './charts'

export default class ChartsGrid extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid">
        {charts.map((chart, i) => 
          <Chart {...this.props} key={i} i={i} chart={chart} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note `charts.map` instead of `this.props.charts.map` because `charts` is directly imported in the file instead of being passed as a prop to the component (as in the 1st solution).

Answer (score 0):

Use [react dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to verify `this.props.charts` is coming in as an array.

If you want a better answer, include the component code that passes `charts` to `ChartsGrid`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call "ChartsGrid" tag and pass a property in that with name 'charts'. Like:

```
<ChartsGrid charts={}...>
```

I am not able to find where you have used 'ChartsGrid' tag.

Answer (score 0):

change ChartsGrid.js to

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from './Chart';

export default class ChartsGrid extends React.Component{
  render() {
   if(this.props.charts){
     return (
       <div className="grid">
         {this.props.charts.map((chart, i) => <Chart {...this.props} key={i} i={i} chart={chart} />)}
       </div>
      )
    }
    else return(
       <div className="grid"></div>
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parent component

Parent.js

```
import ChartsGrid from './ChartsGrid';

const charts = [
  {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
  {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
  {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
];

class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(<ChartsGrid charts={charts}/>)
    }
}
```